# Compiling template header in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

I have a main.cpp and node.h(template) file. It seems to work when I compile only main.cpp that includes node.h. I am wondering if it is okay not to compile node.h?

Comment: Changed the question tag from [c] to [c++] for you, since this is obviously not C.

Comment: 1) There's no such thing as "templates" in C: you probably meant C++, 2) `#include "implementation.hpp` in a .h header is generally a Bad Idea.  Don't do it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the MCVE ([mcve]) I hacked out, which means I'm doing something different from what you did. If you can produce your own MCVE either you'll see what you did wrong while making the MCVE or you'll have something we can use to duplicate what you are doing and be in a much better position to help you.

Comment: Which file are you including from other code? The first or the second header file?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i meant C++ not C

Comment: @paulsm4 so should I compile .h files ? it generates a .gch file that cannot be linked to main.o. what do I do ?

Comment: @tkausl ok I include node.h in my main that uses the node struct. I compiled the main only and it works so I was wondering if it is okay to not compile the node.h

Comment: Q: should I compile .h files ?  A: No, you should `#include` .h files in .cpp source, and compile your .cpp files. SoronelHaetir is correct: the definitions of all templates must be visible in every translation unit in which they are used.  But just `#include` the definition.

Comment: @paulsm4 okay thanks. but then why do we bother to write headers and cpp files separately(non-template) and compile cpp files and then link them to the driver when we could actually implement header files directly and have in included in the driver? That way we wouldn't have to compile anything but the driver only. Is it simply to make it easier to work in groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ compilers generally require that the definitions of all templates be visible in every translation unit in which they are used (the one real exception is if you only allow particular specializations to be used and those specializations are instantiated somewhere, in that particular instance you can get away with hiding the implementation).

Whether you split template declarations from their definitions as you describe is really just a matter of style. Personally I don't care for that as it makes it that much harder to find the actual code for any given template.

However if the code you are dealing with is large enough (as many boost libraries are, for example), then it may well make sense to implement the public template in terms of many private parts and it can well make sense to have those parts be split into their own headers. But again, so long as all the needed code is available in every translation unit it is simply style and one choice is really not any "better" than another so long as it is consistent.